# Need to do correlation in jmeter in such way when values are notfound it should pass nothing

Tags: json, jmeter

I have scenario like for few of uuid details - extra data will be added.

so i need to write regex in way like whenever values are found for regex expression it should pass the same.

if values are not found for regex expression it should not pass nothing in that variable.

Is it possible to handle in Jmeter regex expression?

"include_on_risk_plan_report":true(.*?)},"risk_score":

request1. "include_on_risk_plan_report":1,"kris":[{...}],"origin_name"
response1. "include_on_risk_plan_report":true,"kris":[{...}]},"risk_score":

request2. "include_on_risk_plan_report":1,"origin_name":"
response2. "include_on_risk_plan_report":true},"risk_score":

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're working with [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) and there is no "nothing" there.

You can pass:

- an empty [JSON Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_objects.asp) like `{}`
- an empty [JSON Array](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) like `[]`
- or `null`

There is "Default value" field with the `Use empty default value` option but it might break your JSON request payload:

[image]

Also [JSON is not a regular language](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/is-json-a-regular-language) hence using regular expressions is not the best idea, you might rather want to switch to [JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) instead.